# nsdictionary copy vs mutable copy

Tags: cocoa, copy, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
id dict = [myDictionary copy];
```

but is `dict` now just a regular `NSDictionary`? Or is it a copy of the `NSMutableDictionary`?

Also, is there any way to go from mutable to non-mutable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two methods involved here; `-copy` and `-mutableCopy`.

If the class holds a distinction; `-copy` always creates an immutable copy; and `-mutableCopy` always creates a mutable copy.

If the class holds no distinction; `-copy` always creates a true copy.

So yes, dict is now an NSDictionary, containing the objects in the dictionary.

Comment: Minor correction: `copy` does not create a _deep copy_, so the objects in the copied dictionary will be the same as those in the original one, not copies.

Comment: @omz: Does that also apply if the contents of the dictionary adopt `NSCopying`?

Comment: The Cocoa collection classes always do a shallow copy for the `-copy` method.

Comment: Yes, you would have to explicitly use `initWithDictionary:copyItems:` to create a deep copy.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Yes. The objects in the dictionary make no difference; the copy is always shallow.

Comment: @Williham Totland : hi..can you please explain what do you mean by " class holds distinction".... thanks in advance.

Comment: @Cultor: I feel the meaning of the word should be clear from my answer.

Comment: @Williham Totland : hi, actually I'm a beginner, so didn't understand.